# How to use ng-repeat in array in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, datatable

i have data in this form , employeeObjects is an array and having inside 11 arrays

```
employeeObjects (11) [Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), 
 Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), Array(11), 
  Array(11)]
```

The formation of array inside the employeeobjects is

```
Array(11)
  0 :35
  1:"<div class="media"><img ng-src="app/img/default-user.png" 
  alt="Image" class="img-responsive img-rounded" err-
  src="app/img/default-user.png" 
  onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src=app/img/img-loader.gif"> </div>"
  2:"agent3@email.com"
  3: "agent three"
  4: "agent3@email.com"
  5:"+919098909890"
  6:"iOS"
  7:"3.1.6"
  8:"EagleView"
  9:"<span class="font-size-small font-medium"  
   style="color:#999999">Offline</span>"
  10:"<label class="switch switch custom-switch"  aria-
   hidden="false"><input type="checkbox" ng-
  model="agent_approve[$index]" ng-
  click="agent_status(agent_approve,35)" class="ng-pristine ng-
  untouched ng-valid" aria-checked="true" aria-invalid="false">↵                            
  <span></span> </label>"
 length:11
 __proto__:Array(0)
 1:(11) [34, "<div class="media"><img ng-src="app/img/default-us…
 ror=null;this.src=app/img/img-loader.gif"> </div>", 
 "agent2@email.com", "agent two", "agent2@email.com", "+919098909890", 
 "Android", "3.2.3", "EagleView", "<span class="font-size-small font-
medium" style="color:#63AE0C">Idle</span>", "<label class="switch 
switch custom-switch"  aria-h…   <span></span>↵                        
</label>"]
2:(11) [33, "<div class="media"><img ng-src="app/img/default-us…
ror=null;this.src=app/img/img-loader.gif"> </div>", 
"agent1@email.com", "agent one", "agent1@email.com", "+919098909890", 
"iOS", "3.1.6", "EagleView", "<span class="font-size-small font-
medium" style="color:#63AE0C">Idle</span>", "<label class="switch 
switch custom-switch"  aria-h…   <span></span>↵                        
</label>"]
```

this is demo that iam getting the data in this form .
actually i had the data in the form of datatable . then i have converted it into array . Now suggest me how i can render on html page

Comment: This is a really ugly way to mix data and html especially since it contains angular directives in the html. How do you generate that array in the first place?

Comment: iam getting this by ajax call . If you any idea ..Please suggest me how can i render it on html page

Comment: Do you control the back end also? And where is the associated controller to manage things like `ng-model` data and `ng-click` functions?

Comment: no.. we manage the controller at front-end side .

Comment: But you need a controller scope in order to use `$compile` for any of those directives to even work in the page. This really looks like a bad science experiment gone completely wrong

Comment: earlier we store it in datatables then that becomes easy to handle but now we have convereted into array . Now its becomes too complex for us to handle it .

Comment: What becomes too complex? What you have here by itself is useless if you can't use the scope for it to run `$compile`. What higher level problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: Also in your scraping you didn't even bother to remove form directives like `ng-pristine`

Comment: Actually the main problem we faced in datatable , you can see this code                  
 <label class="switch switch custom-switch"  aria-
   hidden="false"><input type="checkbox" ng-
  model="agent_approve[$index]" ng-
  click="agent_status(agent_approve,35)" class="ng-pristine ng-
  untouched ng-valid" aria-checked="true" aria-invalid="false">↵                            
  <span></span> </label>"     this code is  for toggle (on/off) button and toggle button doesnot work fine in datatables .

Comment: No reason it shouldn't if you integrated datatables properly

Comment: I know this is totally scrap and it is bad science but it becomes mandetory for us to use this scrap

Comment: Why can't you simply pull the data and render it through normal model view methodology? Whatever wierd idea has gone into this concept needs rethinking. Or fix your datatables integration

Comment: If you use toggle button in datatables and you click on a single toggle .All toggle button become active thats the main problem we are facing

Comment: So fix that problem instead of this off the wall hack

Comment: Or use an angular table/grid module

Comment: i have tried to solve that but no solution found till now

Comment: So create a question for that BUT include a **runnable** [mcve]

Comment: Is this closed question?

Answer (score 0):

Although this is certainly not the ideal way to show your data in your view, you can use `ng-repeat` and `$sce` to render your contents in the view. I am assuming that you have the data in controller like this

```
// code in your controller
$scope.employeeObj = [[{obj1}, {obj2}..], [{obj1}, {obj2}..], ...]

// code in view
<div ng-repeat="obj in employeeObj">
    <div ng-repeat="item in obj" ng-bind-html="item"></div>
</div>
```